# pandas dataframeの扱いについて

Tags: python, pandas

次のようなdataframeがあるとします．

```
名前  　年齢
あ　　　NaN
あ　　　20
い　　　30
```

このdataframeに対して，「名前に「あ」を含み年齢がNaNの行の年齢に10を代入する」という処理がしたいです．

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
　 if 'あ' in row["名前"]:
   　　if row["年齢"]!=row["年齢"]:
    　　　 row["年齢"]=10
```

というコードを書いたのですが，元のdataframeに反映されません．

どのように書き変えればよいのでしょうか．ご教授願います．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんか感じででしょうか。

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import nan

df = DataFrame({'名前': ['あ', 'あ', 'い'], '年齢': [nan, 20, 30]})
df.loc[(df['名前'] == 'あ') & (df['年齢'].isnull()), '年齢'] = 10
```